# Change form value before Codeignighter Form Validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have form data posted by client, I want to manipulate one of the forms value before I run it through `$this->form_validation->run()`.

Is this possible

i.e something like;

```
    //Get user form inputs
$input = $this->input->post();

    //generate slug - my custom code
$input['slug'] = sf_generate_slug($input['slug']);


    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    ...
```

Comment: have you tried it? what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reassign any post value before `$this->form_validation->run()` like

```
$_POST['slug'] = sf_generate_slug($_POST['slug']);
```

While if you use your above method it will validate because it didn't overrides the `$_POST` values

Hope it makes sense